# Template literal in argument doesn't work

Tags: javascript, svelte

This returns all png files:

```
const files = import.meta.glob('/static/123456789/*.png')
console.log('files: ', files)
```

But this returns `file: {}`:

```
const dirname = import.meta.env.VITE_DIRNAME
console.log(dirname) // this outputs 123456789
const files = import.meta.glob(`/static/${dirname}/*.png`)
console.log('files: ', files)
```

I tried:

```
if (dirname === '123456789') {
    console.log('yes')
} else {
    console.log('no')
}
```

And it returns `yes`.

I also tried:

```
const mydir = '123456789'
const files = import.meta.glob(`/static/${mydir}/*.png`)
console.log('files: ', files)
```

And this returns `file: {}`.

How can I use variable in the argument?

Comment: Why doesn't work?

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: Did you try doing `dirname === "123456789"`? Maybe there are blank characters

Comment: glob is very particular about whitespace, perhaps what @CristianTraìna suggested helps?

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't tell us much of anything useful. Do you get an error? Or just no matches? Or something else?

Comment: I updated the question. And I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to do, see the documentation of Vite:

| You should also be aware that glob imports do not accept variables, you need to directly pass the string pattern.

https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import